# Possible UI replacement for a select with hundreds of options?

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface

I am in the middle of converting an old Access 2003 app into a web app for an internal project and one of the most prevalent UI elements are `select`s with several hundred elements within them. For example, imagine a data grid of gifts given by benefactors where one column is an option to select which publication (represented by a `select`) was sent to this particular benefactor for this particular gift. But in each row, this same `select` is repeated each time.

I'm worrying about repeating this pattern (firstly, because it's ugly) because of the effects it might have on the browser's performance and, above all, because of the lag it might introduce into the UX. What are some ways I could replace this paradigm with a more modern behavior? I thought, for example, about putting an `<input type="text">` which triggers a modal that presents all the options possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give a look at [select2.js project](https://select2.github.io/) on github, looks perfect in your case.

> Select2 gives you a customizable select box with support for searching, tagging, remote data sets, infinite scrolling, and many other highly used options.

It integrate autocomplete (behave like `<input type="text">`) and is one of the trend project in javascript, hugh community.

Comment: Looks pretty good. Do you have any idea how it performs if there are several dozen of these on a page?

Comment: If you feel on fire :), you can try using [waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) to only generate your .select2() when people scroll on it. This way it can help to initialize step by step instead of all on load. But I think having hundreds of select is and will always be an extreme situation ... to avoid if possible :D. Good luck with that, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: It looks like they recently improved performance a bunch in select2 4.0 so it should work fine. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

In terms of UI, something like this works much better as an autocomplete.

One of the more widely used ones is [jQuery UI's](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). That also gives you the ability to load the data via a remote data source based on what the user enters.

Comment: Would really like to know your opinion about [select2.js](https://select2.github.io/) ? I really like it, light, sexy, and hugh community. jQuery-UI always seems ... heavy to me :(

Comment: @sebastienbarbier It seems pretty nifty actually, to be honest I've never used it myself. I've used chosen.js in the past, but that was a bit clunky and terrible on mobile devices. Is the mobile/tablet support pretty good for select2?

Comment: I agree mobile implementation is supported, but not optimized. It perform exactly as expected but could be improved ... may be there is a mobile addon for it but not that I know. Never heard about chosen.js, I'll give a look ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could have one select with all the options and use that throughout. Basically swap out the current rows select with the actual select with all the options when you edit (or perhaps hover over) that row. Once you finish editing you replace the select with a dummy select which just has one option (the selected one).

Voila! No large DOM or no extreme page loads. It's kind of similar in principle to your suggestion, but it just looks like a plain old heavy page.